# Can I change class?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 1 you could [change class](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090226104300AArVCPn)  for a second playthrough, but you'd lose all XP.

Can I change my class in Mass Effect 3? When can I change it and what happens to my previous progress/level?

I don't mean changing class when importing a ME2 character, I mean after choosing a class in Mass Effect 3. Is there any option when completing the game that allows me to switch class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class is set once you pick one on a new import/creation for ME3.  Unfortunately, your class is retained when you start a new game+ so you cannot change it.  Bonus powers, however, are retained by profile so you can pick a different bonus power.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your class when importing a Mass Effect 2 save, before the tutorial.

You keep your level, but (understandably) you will start out with all your skill points unassigned.